# Error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(

Tags: java, websphere

`Error 500: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;)`

This is the error that I found in `Websphere` but I don't get any error in Apache tomcat. If anybody having solution. please reply me fast.
I am using following jar:
1.) `commons-fileupload-1.3.jar`
2.) `commons-io-2.4.jar`

Comment: your question doesn't make sense?..tell us in briefly what exactly problem are you getting?

Comment: Please check the class loader policy option in WebSchpere, it should be set to "Multiple"

Comment: Can, you ellaborate me , how to set class loader policy.

Answer (score 1):

See 500 means simple there is some problem in servlet code.
you might done something wrong in your servlet code.

try with putting upgraded jar files.

and also put your code so that you have written.

Comment: Friend code which you are saying that is working fine in Apache Tomcat but whe I run same code in Websphere the I got 500 error with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUploadBase.isMultipartContent(Lorg/apache/commons/fileupload/RequestContext;.

Comment: but can you show us the code, so that we can get an idea where it create problem.

Answer (score 0):

A comment on this post helped me, so I'm writing it as an answer.

It may help to set the classloader policy on the server to "Multiple". To do this in Websphere, navigate as follows:

1. Log in to the Websphere console (typically http://localhost:9060/ibm/console/login.do)
2. Servers -> Server Types -> WebSphere application servers.
3. Select the server that your application is deployed on ("server1" by default)
4. In the section "Server-specific Application Settings", change the Classloader policy to "Multiple"
5. Click "OK", then "Save to the master configuration"

You may then need to restart the server before the changes take effect.